# new date() AngularJS time sent from a server GMT to your local computer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, lodash

I get a response from a service and when the service returns it returns with a created server GMT date. The issue arises when I want to display the local date ex: `5-22-2016` I want to change the time to my local computer.

my response looks something like this:

```
createdDate: "2016-04-22 16:48 PM GMT"
description: "File Upload Success"
fileGuid:"62e7250c-d5ed-41e2-b5b2-4600094d9a7c"
fileSize:"191429"
```

There are 90 different objects in my array.
I am trying to use `_each` which iterates through all of my key value pairs:

```
  _.each(data, function(value, key) {
    console.log(key, value);
    var strDateTime = value.createdDate;
    var myDate = new Date(strDateTime);
    data[key].createdDate = (myDate.toLocaleString()).split(',')[0];
    console.log("data", data)
```

But it is working for some of created dates and the others are returning invalid any suggestions

Comment: Any chance you can get the server to respond with an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted date string? These work without issue in the `Date` constructor. Otherwise, I'd recommend parsing the date using something like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: this is where angular is extremely helpful. you can  use the $filter('date') to convert whatever string format into a date object

Answer (score 1):

According to [ECMA-262 5.1 15.9.1.15 Date Time String Format,](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) seems some of your data doesn't in the right format.

> ECMAScript defines a string interchange format for date-times based upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 Extended Format. The format is as follows: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ.

So a better solution would be using the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

With moment.js you can update your code into,

```
moment('2016-5-5').toLocaleString() //'Tue May 05 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0800'
```

Also, for only the showing purpose, there is an angular directive version, [angular-moment.](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment)

Hope this would help. :)

---

Thx for the notice from @RobG, I just replaced the MDN with ECMA-262.

and for `moment("2016-04-22 16:48 PM GMT")`, you can see from the picture below,

[image]

Comment: MDN is not the language specification. While Mozilla browsers may parse such strings correctly, there is no requirement in ECMA-262 for other implementations to parse anything other than a small subset of ISO 8601 formats. And prior to ES5, there was no requirement to parse any string other than the implementation's own output from *toString*. Also, `moment("2016-04-22 16:48 PM GMT")` results in an invalid date.

Comment: First of all, thx for notice. From [ECMA-262 5.1 15.9.1.15 Date Time String Format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), `ECMAScript defines a string interchange format for date-times based upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 Extended Format. The format is as follows: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`.  And I just try to output the `moment("2016-04-22 16:48 PM GMT")` in my console, there is nothing wrong. What version of moment are you using?

Comment: Version 2.10.6 in Chrome 50. Note that if you don't provide a format for the input, moment will guess and if it gets an invalid date, it will toss it to the Date constructor and you get whatever it returns. So you should always provide the input format, otherwise you just don't know what will happen.

Comment: Mine is Version 2.12.  You can see from my screenshot, I didn't set any formatter.

Comment: I can't see your image. Regardless, you should always provide the format. I've updated to v2.13 and while moment.js does parse the string to a valid date, it doesn't do so correctly, it treats the string as local not time zone GMT.

Answer (score 1):

You should manually parse date strings. A library can help, but if you only have one format, a bespoke parsing function is fairly trivial.

If the dates are always GMT and in the format '2016-04-22 16:48 PM GMT', a function like the following may suit.

If you want the output string in a particular format, you can use *toISOString*, which returns a string in ISO 8601 format with GMT time zone, or you can write a small formatting function to generate the format you require.

```js
var s = '2016-04-22 16:48 PM GMT';

// Return a Date given a string in format 2016-04-22 16:48 PM GMT
function parseSpecial(s) {
  var b = s.split(/[-\s:]/);
  var h = (b[3]%12) + (/pm/i.test(s)? 12: 0);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[0], b[1]-1, b[2], h, b[4]));
}

// Return a string in format mm/dd/yyyy hh:ss a given a date
function myFormat(date) {
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n}
  var h  = date.getHours();
  var ap = h > 11? 'pm' : 'am';
  h = h%12 || 12;
  return z(date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + z(date.getDate()) + '/' +
         date.getFullYear() + ' ' + z(h) + ':' + z(date.getMinutes()) +
         ' ' + ap;
}

var d = parseSpecial(s);

document.write(s +   // Original string
          '<br>' + d.toISOString() +  // As ISO 9601 long format string
          '<br>' + myFormat(d)        // As local date and time
          + ' (your local date and time equivalent)');
```

You an use a library to do all of the above, but whether one is necessary or not is up to you. For example, using moment.js, you'd do:

```
// Parse the string, passing the format
var s = '2016-04-22 16:48 PM GMT';
var d = moment(s.replace('GMT','Z'), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a Z');

// Create a string for local time in the required format
console.log(d.format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm a'));
```